# Sending multiple http requests on Openshift, finalized only few

Tags: node.js, request, openshift, node-request

I have build a node.js app for establishing connections with keep-alive, event-stream post request with some external server. I send 400 of them and keep acting on received data using `data` event from *request* node package. I also listen to the `end`, `response` and `error` events.

When I run the application from localhost everything works perfectly according to plan. However, when I push it to Openshift, only first 5 requests work as intended, the rest just... disappears. I don't get any error, I don't get any response, nor *end*. I tried sending the requests in with some delay between them, I tried looking for information about maximum requests, I debugged it thoroughly - nothing works. Does anybody have an idea, basing on this description of the problem, how to make all 400 request work (or have an answer why they won't)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution for that problem myself. It appeared, that the Request.js library couldn't establish more connections then 5 due to the default `agent.maxSockets` property of the `http` server set to that number in 0.10 version of Node.js. Although I had not been requiring `http` package directly, the Request.js library used it. All I had to do to fix that was to put the following code in the main application module:

```
var http = require('http');
http.globalAgent.maxSockets = 500; //Or any other number you want
```

---

Btw. the default value has been changed to *infinity* already in the 0.12 version of Node.js.